# MS Access 2010 - How can I link orphaned records in a child table to newly created parent records?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office, one-to-many

Full explanation:

I've inherited a MS Access 2010 project with a data flow problem that I am not sure how to resolve. The parent table, CASE, has no records. A child table, ACCOUNT, is needs to be linked to CASE as a one-to-many (one case potentially many accounts). The accounts table is populated with several thousand records.

I have a column in ACCOUNT for the primary key of CASE, CASE ID, but I need to populate that column. Since the parent records are empty, the child records don't need to be linked to a particular parent, I just want to assign/link one parent to each of several thousand child records.

Would simply creating the correct amount of CASE records and then populating the CASE ID field in ACCOUNT link those records together? Example: If I create 4000 CASE records, pick an ACCOUNT record, and update the CASE ID field to say '3452', is that all that needs to be done to link that ACCOUNT record to the CASE record with key '3452'?

Then, how would I automate this using an update query or VBA or some other method?

Thanks a ton for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since

> the child records don't need to be linked to a particular parent

you only need to create one CASE record and then run an update query to update CASE ID of the ACCOUNT table to the created ID of that single CASE record.

Comment: Hi Gustav, to clarify, I need to have one ACCOUNT record per one CASE record. It is still a one-to-many because they want to have the option of adding a second ACCOUNT to a CASE later, but for the time being I just need one ACCOUNT to one CASE.